# Re-writing a positional vector in terms of trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, classical-mechanics

A particle of mass $ m $ and position $ \mathbf{r} = x \cdot \mathbf{i} + y \cdot \mathbf{j} + z \cdot \mathbf{k} $ is constrained to a smooth surface described by

$$
x^{2} + z^{2} = 1 + y^{2},
$$
where $ - \pi \leq y \leq \pi $.

Can we write $ \mathbf{r} $ in terms of trigonometric functions?

Comment: maybe y=sin(x) or something and go from there? I am really stumped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x=\sec{\theta} \cos{\phi}$$
$$y=\tan{\theta} $$
$$z=\sec{\theta} \sin{\phi} $$

$\phi \in [0,2 \pi)$, $\theta \in [-\arctan{\pi},\arctan{\pi}]$.

Comment: I'm not sure if im allowed to specify a range for theta? That looks good though! Thanks!

Comment: @JamesT: you have no choice as you specified that problem.  When $y=\tan{\theta}$ and you say that $-\pi \le y \le \pi$, then the bounds on $\theta$ must follow.

Comment: @JamesT: also, if you felt that this solution was helpful, please accept it or upvote it so that it will appear as answered.

Comment: is there anything stopping you from letting cos and sin be functions of theta also?

Comment: Well, if there is some other constraint with respect to the coordinates, then that is possible.  But the transformation I listed completely describes the relations between the coordinates as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

You can write
$$
x= \rho \cos \theta\\
z= \rho \sin \theta\\
y= \pm\sqrt{\rho^2-1}
$$

Comment: would this satisfy −π≤y≤π.?

Comment: no, it wouldn't

Comment: ahh right that is one of the requirements, thanks for the help anyway! :)